# Vuejs mounted возвращает ошибку

Tags: vue.js

Есть такой код:

```
export default {
        data: () => ({
            headers: [{
                text: 'Клиент',
                value: 'name'
            }],
            items: []
        }),
        mounted: {
            this.items = [{}]
        }
    }
```

При комплияции возвращается следующая ошибка:

```
error: Parsing error: Unexpected keyword 'this'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mounted` - это хук, а хук - это функция. Поэтому правильная запись будет такой

```
export default {
        data: () => ({
            headers: [{
                text: 'Клиент',
                value: 'name'
            }],
            items: []
        }),
        mounted() {
            this.items = [{}]
        }
    }
```